# Ubuntu login problem after restoring backuped files from windows

Tags: backup, restore, file-format

Hello this is the description of my problem:

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my inspiron N5010 Laptop.
It runs very well until I restore my backup files. After that operation I can't login my account anymore. I think it's because the format of restored files are ntfs (I backup the whole partition). 
I restored two partitions (F & C) from windows to /home partition in Ubuntu. 
If what I think is true please help me through restoring files in ext4 format or tell me what could I do.

Oh and I used Aomei Backupper to backup my partitions.

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry if I don't write description well. I'm still learning English.

Comment: Which partition are you restoring? Are you trying to put `/home` one a NTFS partition? Please include some more details.

Comment: I'm restoring partition F & D from windows to /home. what kind of details should I add?

Comment: Do you restore the partitions? Do you remove the content already there?

Comment: Yes I restored them. Which contents? Contents in /home?

Comment: If you copied the files to NTFS and back, the files have likely lost their proper access flags (all executables, /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, your use SSH profile... ). If this is the case, it could be faster to reinstall and then **selectively** copy your user files.

Comment: No the backup files are OK. I test them in another laptop with windows 7 and all of them were OK. But in Ubuntu I can't access them. Reinstall what?

Comment: @KouroshDolatmanesh You could reinstall Ubuntu using the preferred method of your choice (for example via a USB drive). During the installation process, you could create a new partition and mount it to ~/home. [Tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/). After the installation finished, you could manually copy the files onto the new partition. For this to work, make sure that you backup your files on an external drive (or use the backup you created earlier)